# Proper exception to raise if None encountered as argument

Tags: python, exception

What is the "proper" exception class to raise when one of my functions detects `None` passed where an argument value is required?  For instance:

```
 def MyFunction(MyArg1, MyArg2):

     if not MyArg2:
          raise ?Error?
```

I think I've seen `TypeError` used here (and it's true that I'm receiving a `NoneType` where some other type is expected) but that doesn't strike me as quite right for this situation where I think the Exception could be more explicit.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this kind of argument checking at all.  Simply let it fail further down with whatever exception it fails with.  (And if you really *must* do this, `TypeError` is the correct exception.  Add an explanation string to make it more specific.)

Comment: I would probably raise a `TypeError`, have a look at the built-in python exceptions documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

Comment: @Sven: I usually do as you suggest, but this is a special case in which I do want this checking done.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There is no "invalid argument" or "null pointer" built-in exception in Python.  Instead, most functions raise `TypeError` (invalid type such as `NoneType`) or `ValueError` (correct type, but the value is outside of the accepted domain).

If your function requires an object of a particular class and gets `None` instead, it should probably raise `TypeError` as you pointed out.  In this case, you should check for `None` explicitly, though, since an object of correct type may evaluate to boolean `False` if it implements `__nonzero__`/`__bool__`:

```
if MyArg2 is None:
    raise TypeError
```

**Python docs**:

- `TypeError` [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) / [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)
- `ValueError` [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) / [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError)

Answer (score 4):

What about creating and using a simple custom NoneException: (maybe it is worth its 2 lines of code)

```
class NoneError(Exception):
    pass

raise NoneError("Object not constructed. Cannot access a 'None' object.")
```

See Python documentation:
https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/#User-defined-Exceptions

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't really need to create a custom exception just for an unexpected None. You should try and use the built-ins exceptions, depends on your specific case. Like other answers mentioned, TypeError or ValueError will cover most common cases.

Comment: It is a personal decision, imho. If you directly want to see, if a field is NONE, than this could indeed be an option with 2 lines of code. It is not making sense for you, but maybe for others. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the python function raises `TypeError` if `None` is passed as an argument. Take any function say `chr(None)` and see it raises `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, `TypeError` or `ValueError` would be natural. If it doesn't seem specific enough, you could subclass whichever of the two exceptions is a better fit. This allows consistent handling of invalid arguments for a broad class of functions while also giving you more detail for the particular function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use assert:

```
assert type(MyArg2) == int
```

Or alternatively:

```
assert type(MyArg2) != None
```

This will prevent someone from passing you the wrong type, as well as dealing with the None issue. It will return an `AssertionError`, [as per the docs.](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)

Comment: This is completely contrary the duck-typing spirit of Python.  It imposes unnecessary restrictions on the applicability of the code. (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: @SvenMarnach  Hmm, I've used it successfully *because of* the duck typing. Namely, the duck typing has hidden *why* something is failing. If you find yourself needing to say this and such must be so before we begin, then assert is merely a convenient way to do so. For instance, write a function with a for loop over an input variable. It is assumed to be a list of file names for globbing. What happens if instead of passing a list with one item, you pass a string with glob chars?

Comment: The problem with the assert is that it ignores values that could serve perfectly well as (in this example) integers, including long integers, floats (under many circumstances, e.g. `range()`), and any object that implements the `__int__()` special method. A better approach, if you feel you need this sort of thing, might be to simply try to coerce the argument to integer early in the method, e.g. `MyArg2 = int(MyArg2)`.

Comment: @kindall Perhaps, but you will note that the asker did not specify what it was he wanted besides not None. I just gave him an option I used previously. If his scope is broader than mine was, then I would agree with you. If he wanted a specific type, then *asserting what you want* is better than *defining errors you know*.

Comment: If he wanted "not `None`", then suggest he assert that, rather than asserting that it's an `int`.

Comment: @kindall I may have jumped the gun a bit. I've seen this proliferation of special cases before though, where you check that it isn't this, and it isn't that. Before you know it, you've checked twelve things it is not, instead of one thing you want it to be.

Comment: Assertions should only be used to test code correctness, not to validate values submitted by a user.